# GET Pedido WooCommerce com critério por Data - restSharp

Tags: c#, api, rest, woocommerce

Pessoal estou fazendo uma integração com C# e a API WooCommerce, minha situação é a seguinte, eu consigo me comunicar com a API através do restSharp e consigo buscar os pedidos do site através da URL de acesso, até aqui tudo bem! Mas, quando tento inserir um critério para a busca (como a data de criação por exemplo), a API me retorna erro 401 - Sem autorização.

Alguém teria uma idéia de como resolver isso? Ou como posso fazer para inserir esse parâmetro na minha requisição?

**Adicionando mais informações:**
A documentação para Woocommerce que sigo é esta no link: http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#authentication-over-http

**E abaixo segue código q estou usando e esta me retornando erro 401:**

```
  var client = new RestClient(URLAPI/orders?after=2018-05-13T16:28:02");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.BuildOAuth1QueryString(client, "CK", "CS");
            var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Nesse caso, teria que ver a documentação da API. se tiver acesso à documentação e quiser postar o trecho que fala de como se autenticar, podemos te ajudar a passar os parâmetros. Não é necessário informar seu dados de autenticação aqui.

Comment: Marcelo a documentação que sigo esta neste link: [link](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#authentication-over-http) "var client = new RestClient("http://meusite.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?after=2018-05-13T16:28:02");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.BuildOAuth1QueryString(client, "ck_527f2f46c5e8ef9adeaad1", "cs_ea20c7b891e31e042fbe2");
            var response = client.Execute(request);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal descobri como resolver minha situação, no meu código faltou inserir a linha **AddQueryParameter**, ficando conforme abaixo:

```
var client = new RestClient("URL/orders");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddQueryParameter("after", "2018-05-13T16:28:02");
            request.BuildOAuth1QueryString(client, "CK", "CS");
            var response = client.Execute(request);
```